# Error Using Callback Function "every"

Tags: javascript, callback

So I'm trying to recreate the "every" method as part of the Eloquent JavaScript exercises. I can't figure out why version two doesn't work (version one works).

The book says that "every returns true only when the predicate returns true for all elements of the array"

**Version One**

```
function every(array, test) 
{
    var boolean = true;

    array.forEach(function(ele) 
    {
        if (!test(ele))
            boolean = false;
    });

    return boolean;
}

console.log(every([NaN, NaN, NaN], isNaN));
// → true
console.log(every([NaN, NaN, 4], isNaN));
// → false
```

**Version Two**

```
function every(array, test) 
{
    array.forEach(function(ele) 
    {
        if (!test(ele))
            return false;
    });

    return true;
}

console.log(every([NaN, NaN, NaN], isNaN));
// → true
console.log(every([NaN, NaN, 4], isNaN));
// → true
```

Comment: Imagine you have these functions: `function foo() { return 'foo'; }; function bar() { foo(); return 'bar'; };`. What does `bar` return when I call it? Then try to transfer this to your version two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In version 2, you're returning from the `forEach()` callback function. That returns to `forEach` function, and it goes on to the next iteration, it doesn't return from the `every` function.

Comment: Interesting. Then is there a way to return from the every function instead?

Comment: No, there isn't. The way you've written the first version is the normal way it's done.